# Flutter How GridView invalid range error with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, gridview

I trying to create `GridView` which it returns `Card Widget`  for `FutureBuilder` and I have 2 fields in Firebase.

GridView's `itemCount: 6`

But there is 2 field in Firebase. So, it return's me something like this:

How can I solve this ?

[image]

FutureBuilder code snipped:

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: collectionRef.get(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                    if (snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                      return GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                        ),
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: 6,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          Map<String, dynamic> docData =
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index].data();
                          if (docData.isEmpty) {
                            return const Text("empty");
                          }
                          String timeSlot = docData['timeSlot'];

                          return Card();
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const Text("error");
                    }
                  } else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    // const LoadingWidget1(height: 50);
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Can you include gridView snippet?

Comment: I added it sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item depends on `snapshot` data length.

Replace

```
itemCount: 6,
```

with

```
itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
```

It will provide exact data length that needs to build on `GridView`.

To create 6 items while handling null data

```dart
itemCount: 6,
  itemBuilder: (c, index) {
    if (index < snapshot.data!.length) {
      //perform any index operation here
      return Card(
        color: Colors.grey,
      );
    } else {
      // you cant perform because data doesnt exit on this index
      /// Map<String, dynamic> docData =
      // snapshot.data!.docs[index].data();
      return const Card(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      );
    }
```

Demo widget

```dart
body: FutureBuilder<List<int>>(
    future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3))
        .then((value) => List.generate(02, (i) => i)),
    builder: (c, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData &&
          snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
          ),
          itemCount: 6,
          itemBuilder: (c, index) => index < snapshot.data!.length
              ? Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text(
                    "${snapshot.data![index]}",
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text("Empty Box"),
                ),
        );
      }

      /// handle others snapshot-state 
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Man, I know it. I just want to create 6 ```Card``` no matter ```snapshot.data?.length.```

Comment: you like to build extra widget for empty item?

Comment: You can  follow `index < snapshot.data!.length`,

Comment: Yes I would like to build extra widget for empty item. But how ?

Comment: you can check my update answer where I am check snapshot length with current index.

Comment: It's not giving what exactly I want. Because, I am trying to build 6 Card. And If there is 2 field in Firebase, let try to set this Card color grey, othervise Card's color yellow.

Comment: I think it important to understand the concept rather than solution. as `index < snapshot.data!.length` return true if data exist, else false. Based on this we return widget  and we are using ternary operator instead of if else. Check update answer of middle portion,

Comment: I agree with you. But not solving this problem.

Comment: Then current issue happening because of inner operation `Map<String, dynamic> docData =
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index].data();`

Comment: Hmm. So why it is ?

Comment: check update answer, you can't perform `docs[index]` when index become >2 where we have data <2. Also if future returning a list you might want `snapshot.data?[index];`

Comment: Oh man you are such an angel! Can I ask you another question ?

Comment: Ok, what is it?

Comment: My Firebase has 4 fields now. How do we access this fields? This method working depends to ```List.generate(03, (i) => i)```

Comment: Oh I got this. I replace it with my own ```future```.

Comment: Yap. Hope you got the issue

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify `itemCount` to the count of fields available in Firebase.

You have 2 fields in your Firebase database and you are  giving a count 6.

Replace your `itemCount` with this:

```
itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
```